# Extracting a portion of the generated Representative Sequences

Tags: r, traminer, sequence-analysis

So, I have a set of 893 sequences of varying lengths with max sequence length = 152. There are 10 unique states across all of them. These sequences are split into two groups: Promoted and Not Promoted. Using TramineR, I generated representative sequence for the two groups (Image attached).

However, I am trying to print out the first 5-10 states of the said representative sequence. Is there a way to do that? [![Representative Sequences] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKivC.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKivC.jpg)

The print can be in the form of color labels or in a string format (preferably color labels)

I could not find any argument in the seqrplot that can help me get what I want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot subset the displayed columns when using `seqrplot` unless you want to find representatives of the truncated sequences. However, you can compute and retrieve the representatives of the complete sequences and then plot the truncated representatives. I illustrate below using the `biofam` data of TraMineR.

```
library(TraMineR)
## biofam data: sequences in columns 10 to 25
data(biofam)
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
                "Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, labels=biofam.lab)
## LCS distances
biofam.lcs <- seqdist(biofam.seq, method="LCS")

## Representative set using the neighborhood density criterion
biofam.rep <- seqrep(biofam.seq, diss=biofam.lcs, criterion="density")

plot(biofam.rep[,6:13])
```

If you have groups, you must compute the representatives separately for each group and then arrange the plots manually using `layout` for example.

Comment: Thanks, but my variable that stores representative sequence is a list. I tried plotting it and obviously it threw error. Here's my code:
`df_seq2_promoted <- df_seq2[df_seq2$X0 == "Promoted",]
df_seq2_prom.seq <- seqdef(df_seq2_promoted[3:619], method = 'OM', right="DEL",format = "SPS", cpal = mycolors_1)
dist.om1_prom <- seqdist(df_seq2_prom.seq, method = "OM", indel = "auto", sm = "TRATE")
rep_seq <- seqrplot(df_seq2_prom.seq, diss = dist.om1_prom, border = NA, criterion = "density")`

Comment: Your `rep_seq` does not store the representative sequences. To get the representative sequences you must use `seqrep` as in the example given in my response.